# Некорректное отображение TextInputEditText в Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-material

Обновляю приложение под Android X. Изначально было Android 6. Сейчас на одном layout есть 2 сom.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
И при тестировании я вижу, что при нажатии на поле ввода, сам инпут как бы пропадает. Его не видно, но он есть. Если нажать на то место, где он есть, то я могу писать в него значения. Чтобы появился инпут, я нажимаю на другой (второй) инпут на layout'е и тогда у выбранного пропадает поле ввода, а на котором я вводил текст - он появляется. Куда копать?
В build.grandle:

```
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 29
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: приложите видео, или скрин, так же код вашего поля для ввода не помешает

Comment: Ссылка на видео https://disk.yandex.ru/i/MChQ93SpwZWdcg
Ссылка на код https://paiza.io/projects/lcmU1ULrqZo-kzEAGEFWLg

Comment: Может что то с темой - используй новые темы для приложения или задай корректную в xml у EditText через android:theme

Comment: И обычно я здесь https://material.io/components/text-fields/android подсматриваю какие атрибуты использовать для TextInputEditText

Comment: xml приложите сюда

Comment: А если использовать НЕ material?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил самостоятельно. Указал цвет рамки и hint